# In Swift, how do I animate a UIView with auto-layout like a page sliding in?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift2

I try to create a UIView that is representing a page whose size is the same as the device screen. Since the app supports orientation, I am using AutoLayout to construct it.

It works fine until I try to animate the page to slide in from the right. Here is the best I could come up with after some research:

```
myView = UIView()
myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
parentView.addSubview(myView)

myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
myView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(parentView.rightAnchor).active = true
myView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(parentView.widthAnchor).active = true
myView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(parentView.heightAnchor).active = true

UIView.animateWithDuration(Double(1.0), animations: {
    self.myView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.parentView.leftAnchor).active = true
    self.myView.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

With the code above, the page `myView` slides in from the top-left corner, which is not what I am expecting and the log also says `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints`.

Any advise to help me and correct me for better understanding AutoLayout and animation is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You missed the top anchor.

Comment: @dasdom even I add the top anchor, it's the same. The problem is that I thought I was overwriting an existing rules but actually I am creating new rules. So the solution is to deactivate some rules first before creating new ones. I think I have found the solution, I will post the answer later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my original question, I thought I was overwriting an existing rule (the left anchor) but actually I was creating a new rule for the left anchor, therefore the conflict and failure to animate.

With the help from @vacawama [in the other question about changing AutoLayout rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34391732/how-to-change-auto-layout-constraints-after-they-are-set-when-using-constrainteq/), it is working now as below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let myView = UIView()
    myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(myView)

    myView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor).active = true
    myView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.widthAnchor).active = true
    myView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.heightAnchor).active = true

    var leftConstraint = myView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.rightAnchor)
    leftConstraint?.active = true

    myView.layoutIfNeeded()

    /* try to deactivate a rule and create a new rule, then animate it */
    leftConstraint?.active = false
    leftConstraint = myView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leftAnchor)
    leftConstraint?.active = true

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0) { self.view.layoutIfNeeded() }
}
```

But if I change the last line to call `layoutIfNeeded()` on `myView` instead, it's not animating (any comment is welcome). I actually want to call it on a subview instead of a parent view because I don't want all subviews to animate (in a complete use case). So it probably needs some workaround, but the basic concept is there and have solved the original question.